# Extreme CPU load

Tags: central-processing-unit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How Can Linux Top Show 2% Idle, but Load Say 1.20?](https://serverfault.com/questions/269708/how-can-linux-top-show-2-idle-but-load-say-1-20)

Something strange has suddenly happend and I need help. top shows only 1 running process with >300 waiting. CPU load is > 100, but only a few %. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

There might be processes in IOWait contributing to the higher load.

One way of finding those is by running this command:

```
ps fauxw  | awk '$8 == "D" { print }'
```

Comment: There are some processes with D, but most are S or Ss.